# How upgrading of a Odoo module works?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have two databases in odoo `DB1` and `DB2`. I made some changes to existing modules(say `module1` and `module2`) in `DB1` through GUI(web client). All those changes were stored to `DB1` and were working correctly when I am logged in through **`DB1`**.

Now, I made some changes in few files(in same two modules `module1` and `module2`). These modules need to be upgraded in order to load those changes. So, i logged in from `DB2` and upgraded those modules. My changes in file loaded correctly and were working correctly when I am logged in through **`DB2`**.

But those file changes were loaded only for `DB2` and not for `DB1`.

So, I wanted to know:

1. How upgrading of a module works?? Does it upgrades only for the database through which the user is logged in and upgraded the module?
2. And if it is so. Then, is there a way that I can Upgrade my module while retaining all the previous changes that i made through the GUI in that same module?
3. What are the things that are changed when a module is upgraded?

Answer (score 4):

There is 2 step for upgrading an addons in Odoo,

First, restarting the service. it will upgrade your .py files.
Second, click upgrade button in Apps>youraddonsname. it will upgrade your .xml files.

i create a script for upgrading the XML files. the name is upgrade.sh

`#!/bin/sh
for db in $(cat /opt/odoo/scripts/yourlistdbfiles);
do
odoo --addons-path=/opt/odoo/youraddonspath -d $db -u youraddonsname --no-xmlrpc > /opt/odoo/logs/yourlogfiles.log 2>&1 &
sleep 20s && exit &
done`

so you just run sh /opt/odoo/script/upgrade.sh after editing your addons and no need to click the upgrade button anymore.

hope this help

Comment: So, will it retain the changes that i made through the GUI or revert them back to the code in files?

Answer (score 3):

you can restart the server and start the server by `python odoo-bin -d database_name -u module_name`
or -u all to update all module

Comment: That only works when changes are made in python code. It does not work XML changes. For XML you have to upgrade your module. Also, restarting server will not work when changes are made in model such as adding a field or removing it. Please read the question again.